# Найти файл, где формируются цены заказа при получении письма в плагине WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

На сайте настроил корзину WC, прописал недостающие составляющие для формирования цены. При оформлении заказа цены отображаются корректно, а вот клиенту на емейл идёт письмо с неправильными значениями. В каком конкретно файле калькулируются эти значения? Шаблон письма - customer-on-hold-order.php Но где сама калькуляция цен?

Comment: Цена чего? Продукта или общая/подитог?

Comment: @Алексей и общая и всего, так как и там и там ошибки в расчётах, которые я хочу исправить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите экшн `woocommerce_email_order_details` хук `WC_Emails::order_details()` через него выводится цены на товары и итог заказа

Если кратко то используются шаблоны `woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-details.php`
и `woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-items.php` - для вывода товаров.

Comment: спасибо, помогли!